# Consume NON WS-I complient in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I have following service which needs to be consumed in Visual Studio without changing WSDL (as wsdl is third party). It is non compliant WS-I Profile. So it gives error while consuming. Is there any way, I can generate c# class for this WSDL file using another software or commands.

http://kunden.netdirekt.de/soap/services.wsdl

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and .NET are you using? What technique to you use to attempt to consume the service? "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Contact the author of this service. WSDL.exe and soapUI both are not able to understand this service.

Comment: I am using .NET studio 2008. And contacting author ..no meaning as in SoapUI, I can consume and run the service. Just as it is non complient WS-I, wsdl can't generate class and so how can i use this in .NET ?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a daunting task, but you could try writing an XSLT transformation to transmogrify this non-compliant ersatz-WSDL to a format digestible by `wsdl.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL is not parsable by the .NET framework, either by WSDL.EXE or SVCUTIL.EXE.

The elements that the tools object to are the unresolved references to soapenc:Array

As @Pradeep suggests, contact the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

It is all just XML in the end...., so if need be you could craft your own XML requests and then process the XML that comes back.  Very painful, but that is what people have to do outside of the .net world every day.

Comment: But can't we generate or make some classes some way that can do this work. Any suggestion. Or do we need to dig this manually.